# Someone has intentionally downvoted all of my questions. What should I do?

Tags: discussion, support, downvotes

Someone [has intentionally downvoted](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5104596/trix?tab=reputation) **at once**, all question I have asked before, resulting in about 100 reputation loss. What should I do?

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/126829/236563

Comment: at least one downvote was not from the same user (one of your questions got 2 downvotes).

Comment: No problem! they'll be reversed :) if multiple down votes are all from the same user.. I wonder why would someone use all his daily votes to just down votes a single user

Comment: This does look like a clear case of serial down-voting. If all the votes haven't been invalidated overnight use the "contact us" form to ask a CM to invalidate the remaining ones. Point them at this comment so they know it's a legitimate request.

Comment: @ChrisF: Only 16 downvotes (presuming they were on questions) were reversed and 39 are still in effect (all within about 8 minutes).

Comment: @PeterMortensen All the votes were reversed by a CM. There's a "Voting Corrected" entry on the 22nd and there are no suspicious votes showing up. If the posts you're looking at have down-votes then they must have come from other users.